# Button to save document doesn't work as expected

Tags: xpages

I would like my "save" button to make a change in the document, to save the document , to give a confirmation message, and to refresh.

When using the following code on an iPhone I have to click 2 times before getting the confirmation message and the document doesn't refresh. When using the same code in Google chrome I get the confirmation message after 1 click, but the document or page also doesn't refresh. What's wrong?

```
<xp:button value="Save" id="button1" style="mybutton;font-size:14pt;font-family:Arial">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:actionGroup>
                <xp:executeScript>
                    <xp:this.script>
                        <![CDATA[#{javascript:value1 = viewScope.get("client");
                            document1.replaceItemValue("visNrClient",value1);}]]>
                    </xp:this.script>
                </xp:executeScript>
                <xp:saveDocument var="document1"></xp:saveDocument>
                <xp:confirm message="SAVED !!"></xp:confirm>
            </xp:actionGroup>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Comment: xp:confirm is supposed to be used to ask the user a question, like "Are you sure?" and provide them with Ok/Cancel choices. You should actually use some script to provide them confirmation that the action completed instead of giving them an Ok/Cancel choice, which may confuse them.

Answer (score 1):

Are you moving from the same component in both cases? If you have onblur or onchange code on the component you were in, if that triggers a partial refresh, that will run and take precedence over the button click event, which would explain the need to click twice.

Comment: On the same page I have a combobox with an onchange event. How could I solve this ?

Comment: I'm not sure of a clever standard approach. I'm not sure if the partial refresh post will have a handle on where the user has clicked, to allow you to get around it.